# Returning an Observable from a Promise that returns an Observable

Tags: angular, promise, observable

I have the following function:

```
public isAuthenticated(): Observable < boolean > {
  return fromPromise(this.renewTokens()
    .then(() => {
      return this.fetchUserData().pipe(map(user => {
        // store the user object somewhere
        return user !== null;
      }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.ctx.log.error('Token renewal error', error);
      return false;
    }));
}
```

Where I'm trying to renew the user token first (function `renewTokens()` that returns a `Promise`) then get the user profile using the `fetchUserData()` function which returns `Observable<User>`. I would like to store this user profile somewhere and then return an `Observable<boolean>` as shown.

Of course the above returns `error TS2322: Type 'Promise<boolean | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.` which I totally understand but have no idea how to resolve.

Notice that I'm not trying to subscribe to `fetchUserData()` here yet, I'd like the caller of `isAuthenticated()` to do this. That would typically happen in Angular's [`CanActivate` Router Guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Comment: Looks like you got an `Observable<Observable<…>>` that you would need to flatten at some point

Comment: What's with the `map` in the `pipe()` call?

Comment: Thank you, that’s what I was hoping to find out how to do! The `pipe(map(...))` exists because `fetchUserData()` returns an `Observable<User>` while I’m supposed to return an `Observable<boolean>`. But also because before returning anything I need to store the value of `user` returned by `fetchUserData()` — since I’m assuming that whoever will call `isAuthenticated` will `subscribe` to it, I’m hoping that code (storing the user) will always be executed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just need to flatten the inner Observable (I didn't test this but I hope you'll get the point):

```
return fromPromise(this.renewTokens())
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.fetchUserData()
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          // store the user object somewhere
          return user !== null;
        })
      );
    ),
    catchError(error => {
      this.ctx.log.error('Token renewal error', error);
      return of(false);
    }),
  );
```

Comment: I see what you're doing; I've never found a reasonable enough description of `concatMap` for such a usage. Are we they obliged to use the first `fromPromise` and `pipe` or do you think this could be further optimised? I see that you totally removed the `.then()` and `.catch()` blocks.

Comment: I'm assuming `this.fetchUserData()` returns Observable. If not you'll need to wrap it with `fromPromise`. I don't understand what problem you have with `concatMap`

Comment: You assume correctly! Absolutely no problem, except I’ve never used it before and I need to know why it would solve the issue vs. flatMap, switchMap, and mergeMap that I have affectively try to use to the same aim. But that’s my research task :)